# Dynamic Javascript using Scala template

Tags: playframework-2.1

I am trying to localize my Javascript files. For instance, I would have:

```
var count = 0;
$('#choices .choice').each(function(i) {
    $('input', this).each(function() {
        count++
        $(this).attr('placeholder', '@Message("placeholder.choice") ' + count)
    })
})
```

This would obviously work if the Javascript file is inside the Scala HTML template but I would prefer to have it in a dedicated file.

To begin with, I am wondering if it is a good idea: what about caching file if it's content may change? In this case, there is a single parameter: having it in the URL would solve this problem? Eg: `/assets/javascripts/:lang/my-file.js`.

And the real question is: is it possible to do that using Play! framework? It does not seem that Javascript templates are supported (or I missed something). Is there a way to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to translate your JavaScripts dynamically, it's reduntant waste of resources, instead prepare static JS files like `messages.en.js`, `messages.de.js` etc and include required file basing on the user's language directly into the view.

[Here you have some description how to make it easy](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/blog/2010/12/01/javascript-string-localization-done-right/) (JavaScript approach)

Answer (score 1):

There is a module allowing javascript internationalization using the same mechanism as in Play templates, have a look at :
https://github.com/julienrf/play-jsmessages

This will definitely fits your needs. I use it for a while know with success. You can expose your translations through a javascript file and then use browser caching with a proper fingerprinting configuration.