# Play Framework template that is actually a JS file

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I'd like to have a Play template that is a JS file (as opposed to having `<script>` tags inside an HTML template). The reason for this is so that the script can be cached. However, I need to create a differences in the script depending on where it's included and hoped to do this with Play's template system. I can already do so if I use embedded scripts, but those can't be cached.

I found [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763655/dynamic-javascript-using-scala-template) that also asks the same thing, but the answer is totally different (different goals).

Comment: You can define your javascript files as Play templates. Just like you do for html templates. You only need to add your template and render it from a controller and add a route. But always there are better ways than creating a dynamic javascript. As for caching, what if you create a normal javascript file and serve it with play? You think it won't be cached? Why?

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari, I didn't say that a normal JS file wouldn't be cached. Rather, I need to be able to substitute data into the file with Play and serve an actual JS file and not embedded JS code (in the HTML).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's easy, just... create view with `.js` extension, i.e.: `views/myDynamicScript.scala.js`:

```
@(message: String)

alert('@message');

//Rest of your javascript...
```

So you can render it with **Scala** action as:

```
def myDynamicScript = Action {
  Ok(views.js.myDynamicScript.render(Hello Scala!")).as("text/javascript utf-8")
}
```

or with **Java** action:

```
public static Result myDynamicScript() {
    return ok(views.js.myDynamicScript.render("Hello Java!"));
}
```

Create the `route` to you action (probably you'll want to add some params to it):

```
GET   /my-dynamic-script.js      controllers.Application.myDynamicScript()
```

So you can include it in HTML templite, just like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Application.myDynamicScript()'></script>
```

**Optionally:**

You can also render the script into your HTML doc, ie by placing this in your `<head>...</head>` section:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    @Html(views.js.myDynamicScript.render("Find me in the head section of HTML doc!").toString())
</script>
```

Edit: [*@See also samples for other templates types*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14625097/1066240)

Comment: I would hate for this to sound like a "me too" thank you however this actually solved a **completely different problem** I'm having with play's SBT submodule setup versus static assets. I now no longer have to solve *that* problem as this is all I need to work-around the challenge. So thank you :)

Comment: I am searching for more details about this topic. Would you please be able to point to the source of this information? I cannot find it anywhere else.